# Todo list на Vue - Не могу решить вопрос с checbox "checked"

Tags: vue.js

Ну история такая, реализация простого todo list, но все разбито на компоненты (Ну да это и не так важно). 
[image: Вот пример)]
Вот что-то не могу придумать как это реализовать, чтобы статус `checked`, сохранялся у `checkbox`.
На картинке видно, что после того как одной заметке поставлен статус completed он зачеркивается и Все сохраняется в `Localstoreg`. Но статус checkbox сбрасывается

Родитель ловит событие `@confirm-todo="confirmTodo"`

```
<div class="todo-body">
  <ul class="todo-body__list">
    <TodoElement
      v-for="(todo, i) of todos"
      :key="todo.id"
      :todo="todo"
      :index="i"
      @delete-todo="deleteTodo"
      @confirm-todo="confirmTodo"
    ></TodoElement>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Вот есть todo элемент

```
<template>
  <li class="todo-element">
    <span class="todo-info">
      <input type="checkbox" class="todo-check" @change="confirmTodo">
      <strong> {{ index + 1 }} :</strong>
      <p class="todo-text" :class="{done: todo.completed}">Title:  {{ todo.title }} </p>
    </span>
    <div>
      <Button class="todo-button__edit">
        <template>Edit</template>
      </Button>
      <FunctionsButton class="todo-button__delete" @click="deleteTodo">
        <template>Delete</template>
      </FunctionsButton>
    </div>
  </li>
</template>
```

Вот полетел `$emit` метод изменения статуса 'confirmTodo'

```
  methods: {
    deleteTodo () {
      this.$emit('delete-todo')
    },
    confirmTodo () {
      this.todo.completed = !this.todo.completed
      this.$emit('confirm-todo')
    }
  }
```

Ну и как говорил ранее что у родителя ловлю))
И делаю вот такую жесть с ним))
`saveLocalStorageTodos()` - Функция запись в LocalStorage

```
confirmTodo () {
      this.todos.includes({
        completed: true
      })
      this.saveLocalStorageTodos()
    }
```

Вот такие дела, хотелось бы как-то сохранять статус `checkbox` в `localStorag`, но не могу придумать как
Разбередил примеры многих todo, но чет не смог примерить(
как то нужно прикрутить watch походу, но опыта у меня совсем мало. Вот и тут уперся чет.
Буду рад любой подсказке.
Ну и если что, вот ссылка на репу: https://github.com/PIPSKVIK/My-todo
Всем хорошего дня!!!

Comment: ```<input type="checkbox" class="todo-check" @change="confirmTodo">```. Думаю, что проблема в том, что значению чекбокса неоткуда взяться. Но я могу и ошибаться. Тут чтобы разобраться нужно чуть больше данных. Страница обновляется при возникновении события?

Comment: Попробуйте привязать значение через v-bind или v-model. Взять значение надо будет из хранилища

Comment: @ЖекаДиулин, страница не обновляется.
Ну вроде как логично использовать v-model="" Но что-то я не могу придумать как это все потом в методесделать

Comment: А напрямую из хранилища не получится? Оно реактивное или не очень?

Comment: Ну вот делю так:
`<input type="checkbox" class="todo-check" @change="confirmTodo" v-model="checked">`
В этом же компоненте создаю data
` data () {
    return {
      checked: false
    }
  }`

Потом пропсом поймал у родителя 
`props: {
    checked: Boolean
  }`

И более дурацкий метод я не придумал))

`  confirmTodo () {
      this.todos.includes({
        completed: true
      })
      this.checked = true
      this.saveLocalStorageTodos()
    }`

Comment: @ЖекаДиулин, ну получить я его могу, а вот как дальше с ним быть.
Что-то уже окончательно запутался)))

Comment: К сожалению я не Нэо и не вижу мир в коде! Точно знаю, что дочерние компоненты что-то сообщают родителю через события, а через свойства данные идут от родителя в дочерние компоненты.Так что это не дурацкий, а вполне нормальный метод.

Comment: Пользуетесь Vue Devtools? Попробуйте отловить ошибку там

Comment: @ЖекаДиулин - спсибо за комменты. Сейчас буду пробовать еще))

Comment: Всегда рад что-то подсказать!)